# Attached Command

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, command

**TL;DR** Is it possible to attach an asynchronous cancellable command to the `Parent-View-Model` which is containing the child

My problem is, I have a `ViewModel` for a `View` which is displaying a "**WizardControl**"(like an installation-assistant, where you can click next to get to the next View)
[image: Wizard Control]

The `Log in` Button is part of the `Parent-View-Model`, and the Command to execute for this Button has to be a combination of the Command from the `Specific Page`(aka the child) and the `MainWindow`(aka the parent).

Right now I am executing the command of the child within the command of the parent:

```
ForwardCommand = new DelegateCommand(() =>
{
    CancelEventArgs cea = new CancelEventArgs();
    if (NextCommand != null)
    {
        NextCommand.Execute(null, cea));
        if (!cea.Cancel)
        {
            //Go to next page
        }
        //Else stay on that page because an error occured while the command
    }
},
(nul)=> {
    if (NextCommand != null)
    {
        return true;
    }
    return NextCommand.CanExecute(nul);
});
```

This works, as far as the containing command has no need of being executed asynchronously, which is the case for the `Login`. Because then the next page is shown, without the user being logged in to get data needed on the next page. (A loading bar would be shown at the first page while logging in). For the case an error occurs while executing the `Child-Command` I implemented the CancelEventArgs as you can see in the code.

Thanks in advance,
Flo

PS. `The DelegateCommand` is a Self-Made Implementation extended by the `CancellationEventArgs`

**EDIT:**
My implementation before the `Attached Commands` was that I had an extra "Log In" button on the page to click, and only allowed to go the next step when the user was logged in, but that is bad user experience

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why does it have to be a command? If you don't want to bind the login functionality directly to a button, don't provide a command, use a method:

```
ForwardCommand = new DelegateCommand( async () =>
{
    if (await _currentlyShownWizardPage.DoYourStuffThatHappensWhenTheUserClicksNext())
        GoToNextPage();
});
```

Alternative way is to build it the other way round: bind the wizard page's command to the next button (together with the button content also provided by the wizard page), and have the wizard page's command advance the wizard to the next page (through an `IWizard` service provided to the wizard page).

Comment: The reason why I chose a Command is because I also need the logic for the can-next, so basically the average reasons to choose a Command in a ViewModel ^^

Comment: `ICommand` screams *bind me to a button*... if you use it inside your (business) logic, you're probably confusing the user, as well as sacrificing flexibility, because the `ICommand.Execute` is not `async` and its parameter is just an object, just to name the two most obvious limitations. More problematic is the whole `CanExecute`/`Execute`-system when you move away from the ui because you leave the context of a single ui thread. In general, even if `CanExecute` returns true, the moment you call `Execute` it could be false (and vice versa), making it meaningless in a way.

Comment: To make the stuff threadsafe I implemented `if (Interlocked.Read(ref isExecuting) != 0)` and `Interlocked.Exchange(ref isExecuting, 1);`, so when executing I set it to 1, and otherwise to 0, in a threadsafe manner.
_ICommand screams bind me to a button_: Basically that's what I want, I want to bind a command to a button, buut my button is inside of the ``ParentView``, with another ``ViewModel`` responsible for it.
I need the parameter only for one Command which is the login-command for security reason (PasswordBox-Problems)

Comment: So basically it would be the easiest, if I could have the "Next" button in the specific Views and bind a command directly to it. But that would break the DRY-principle, because I would implement the button for every view.

Comment: DRY is for classes you design, if some ui guy creates screen designs where every screen has the same button, it's not your fault ;-)

Comment: My solution now is your _alternative way_. I bind the command of the current page directly to the button and call in the page(aka the child) `GoToNextPage()` which tells the parent to go to the next page.